# How to change the text position?

Tags: css, html, sass

[Please see the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9jLM.png)

Yes i want to change the position of the text.

This is just HTML for this....

```
<div class="color-traces">
  <span class="rejected-by-admin">
   <strong>
    Rejected by Admin
   </strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

Sass styles are here:

```
.color-traces
  span
    padding: 03px 10px 20px 10px
    border-radius: 25px

.rejected-by-admin
  background-color: #cc1a1a !important
  color: #000 !important
```

Please do share your feedback.
I want text to be centralized equally from all sides.

Answer (score -1):

To center text in a container, use

```
text-align: center;
```